# Hebrew/English bracket placement in short English passage using XeTeX and polyglossia is wrong

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew

The following is a minimal example of the broken bracket placement I observe using Hebrew and English in one document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
% sans serif fonts in math mode
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  SlantedFont=cmunsi,
  BoldFont=cmunsx,
  ItalicFont=cmunsi,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunso
]{cmunss}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage[calendar=hebrew]{hebrew} 
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial Unicode MS}% or whatever
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

תופעה ייחודית בטבע\\

\[(x^2+ y^2+ z^2)^2 = x^2+ y^2\]
הנה דוגמא
\foreignlanguage{english}{ (Here is an example)}
הנה דוגמא
\end{document}
```

The same error ocurrs, when I use

```
    \begin{english} (my English) \end{english}.
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What's wrong with `\textenglish{(Here is an example)}`?  Why do you need the `\foreignlanguage` macro there?

Comment: The placement of the brackets are correct: You have four words "(Here", "is"   "an" and "example)". The characters in the word are printed left to right, but the words follow the direction of the line and are printed right to left. To change also the printing order of the words you must use `\textenglish` - it adds an extra `\LRE` around `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: Thanks! \textenglish works great...I didn't realise that was an option.